# Auto deploy NetBeans to Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I'm creating an JSF application with NetBeans8. When I run the project its should automatic deploy to Tomcat but doesn't work, I need deploy manually at manager of Tomcat.

Looking for a solution I found an suggest to add this at pom.xml: `<netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat80</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>` I added but still doesn't work

I'm using: Maven + NetBeans8 + Tomcat8

**Solved the problem**

The problem is with permissions of Tomcat. I edited `tomcat-users.xml` with permissions and now works.

here how i did

```
<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui" username="tomcat"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1" username="both"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="role1" username="role1"/>
    <!--user and password -->
    <user password="mypass" roles="manager-script,admin" username="tomcat"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you deploy it from netbeans? Are you getting errors? Do you have tomcat setup in netbeans? Is the project run configuration setup to deploy to tomcat?

Comment: @peeskillet
Tomcat8 is installed and running. Netbeans8 no return errors or exceptions when I do run project. Netbeans8 is generating war file normally and I do deploy normally. The problem is that netbeans is not making automatic deploy